# Split union declaration in GraphQL schema over multiple lines

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

I have a GraphQL-schema that has a union declaration that already has a lot of types, e.g.:

`union SectionUnion = SectionForm | Section2 | Section3 | Section4 | Section5`

I know that lots more sections are coming (not added yet) and at some point the union declaration will become unreadable, as it would be a very long line.

Is there a way to put the types in multiple lines, one type per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White space (spaces and tabs), line terminators and commas are all ignored characters in GraphQL. So this definition is equally valid and equivalent:

```
union 
 SectionUnion    = 
SectionForm |
    Section2
| Section3

,
  | Section4   | ,,,  Section5
```